# How do I get the indexes of unique row for a specified column in a two dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy index like this....

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
])
```

How would I find the index of the rows where the values in one or more specified columns are unique?  What I mean is...  If I specify a column as a "mask" how would I find the unique rows using that column as a mask?  For example, if I wanted...

Unique rows with respect to column 0 (column 0 is the mask).  I would want a return like this....

```
[[0,1],[2,3]]
```

because if you were to use column 0 as the criteria for uniqueness rows 0 and 1 would be in the same "unique group" and rows 2 and 3 would be in another "unique group" because they have the same value in column 0.

If I wanted the rows with respect to column 1 (column 1 is now the mask) I would like to have an output like this....

```
[[0,2],[1,3]]
```

because using column 1 as the criteria for uniqueness would result in rows 0 and 2 and rows 1 and 3 being in their own separate unique groups because they have the same values in column 1

I also want to be able to get the unique rows with respect to more than one column  So if I wanted the unique rows with respect to column 0 AND 1 (now both column 0 and 1 are the mask) I would want this return....

```
[[0],[1],[2],[3]]
```

because when you use both columns as your uniqueness criteria there are four unique rows.

Is there an easy way to do this in numpy?  Thanks.

Comment: It's ambiguous which row of the duplicated key row that you want. For example should it produce `[0, 0]` or `[0, 1]`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by key row.  Can you elaborate on that please?  I am looking for the index of each row using the column as a "mask".  So if I use column 0 as my mask I would want [0,1] and [2,3] as my return values because these are the rows that are unique using column 0 as the criteria for uniqueness.  I will update my question.

Comment: You're essentially asking for a `GROUP BY` like SQL operation, but if you do a `GROUP BY`, you must provide an aggregation function for the remaining columns. Do you want the first value, the last value, the min value, the max value? In the example, if you use column 0 both `[0, 0]` and `[0, 1]` are duplicates for `0`, but either is an appropriate return value. You need to have additional selection criteria for which of the duplicates you want to keep.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  Yes, if I use column 0 as my criteria I would get both [0,0] and [0,1] as duplicates for 0.  In my case I don't want to create an additional selection criteria for which duplicate to keep.  I would want to keep the row indexes of both.

Comment: I see, you want the partitioned groups of indices to be returned, not the orginal row values. It is just coincidental that `[0, 1]` is also a *member* of your `a` array. That was what was confusing.

Comment: Yup!  Exactly.  I'm hoping the solution will be easier than describing the problem  :D  Numpy is usually great that way, but I'm having a hard time with this particular problem.

Comment: This seems like a fairly specialized operation, and I don't know of any built-in solution, but if you're willing to allow a custom solution, it can be done.

Comment: You can probably use `NP.unique` and the `return_inverse` parameter to get the indices of the unique elements.  You would then have to group them using the unique array.

Comment: A few more questions: 1) Are the values in the column sorted by the column in which you are interested? 2) If the values aren't sorted, do you need globally unique values to be grouped or just adjacent unique values? 3) Are you only needing this for Nx2 arrays, or do you need this to work for NxM arrays?

Comment: The example I gave is a very watered down version of what I will be working with.  I am dealing with NxM arrays, the number of rows and columns will change from dataset to dataset.  The values in the column are not always sorted.  I do need the indexes for all globally unique values (all rows) with respect to the column(s)

Comment: It would be best to update your question with some of those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a custom solution that is certainly not going to be very performant since it does a lot of copying and directly iterates over the matrix:

```
def groupby(a, key_columns):
    from collections import defaultdict
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for i, row in enumerate(a):
        groups[tuple(row[c] for c in key_columns)].append(i)
    return groups.values()
```

This assumes `key_columns` is a list or tuple that contains the corresponding columns for which you are interested in doing the grouping over. You could also do some argument inspection and promote a single index into a singleton list.

Running the following examples yields this output:

```
>>> groupby(a, [0])
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> groupby(a, [1])
[[0, 2], [1, 3]]
```

It also works for multiple key columns like you asked:

```
>>> groupby(a, [0, 1])
[[1], [2], [0], [3]]
```

Note in this case, since a `defaultdict` is used, the order of the values is not guaranteed. You could either sort the resulting values or use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead depending on how you plan to use the secondary indexes.

Comment: Yes, this does the job.  Seems fast enough for my use.  It doesn't have to be blazing fast because I only need to call it once for the entire analysis of the data set.  Once these indexes are "pre-computed" the class I use them in stores them so it can use them over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Try using itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [1,3,2,3,4,1,5,2,6,3,4]
data = [(x, k) for k, x in enumerate(data)]
data = sorted(data)

groups = []
for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x:x[0]):
    groups.append([x[1] for x in g])

print(groups)
```

Output is

```
[[0, 5], [2, 7], [1, 3, 9], [4, 10], [6], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way, using a loop:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
])


un = numpy.unique(a)

results = []

# could be a list comprehension
for val in un:  

    # zero-th column, change as needed:   
    indices = a[:,0] == val  

    results.append(numpy.argwhere(indices).flatten())

result = numpy.array(results)

print result
```

Depending on your needs and ultimate goals, you could use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

It has a `groupby` method you could use like this:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
])


df = pandas.DataFrame(a).groupby([0])  # zero-th column, change as needed

for key, group in df:
    print group.values
```

Notice that this returns the actual values, not the indices.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the indexes.  I may consider pandas if I can't get this to work in numpy

Comment: I'll add a pure numpy answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) provides a fully vectorized solution to these kind of problems:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
# entire rows of a determine uniqueness
npi.unique(a)
# only second column determines uniqueness
npi.unique(a[:, 1])
```

And many more column types are possible as well.